# How to remove unwanted aftertaste from food

Tags: chocolate, hot-chocolate

So I've just finished making about a liter of hot chocolate (lets ignore why for a minute here), and I've stored it in my refrigerator, inside a plastic bottle that was once used to store orange juice. Although I cleaned and rinsed the bottle as well as I could before using it, the hot chocolate has taken on an orange-y aftertaste. It's by no means inedible, but unwelcome nonetheless.

Is there any way to remove/mask the flavor? I'd hate to have to throw all this out.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no universal means.  Don't store strongly flavored liquids in plastic bottles you would like to reuse.

In the specific case of hot chocolate, it is ammenable to a number of strong flavors which may mask the odd orangey aftertaste.  I would recommend re-heating it with a pinch of cayenne pepper (really; hot pepper and chocolate go nicely), and perhaps a couple of cardamom pods if you enjoy their unique flavor.

Comment: Would cinnamon work? I just happen to have a lot of that on hand.

Comment: Its pretty strongly flavored; you could try it.  If you *like* orange and chocolate you could also try orange zest.